# Package hyperref Error Wrong DVI mode driver option dvipdfm

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

So, I am writing my dissertation using Latex (Texmaker). Last week I installed fresh windows and suddenly texmaker after that is not compiling the files. I am not sure why, because when i copy same files to my computer (which I am using remotely), the code compiles flawlessly.  Following is the error I am seeing in log

**! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvipdfm',
(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.
See the hyperref package documentation for explanation.
Type H  for immediate help.**

Note: Before writing my question, I did search about it online and it says that I should not be using dvipdfm for latex as the output would be dvi. However, I have been using the same codes and files before installing the windows and it worked but now i am receiving this error.

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that when i use Winedt to compile the files, it works but only if uncomment the bibliography, with bibliography it gives an error as following:

latex error something's wrong--perhaps a missing item

Comment: you seem to use pdflatex or lualatex. Then don't use the dvipdfm option for hyperref.

Comment: you are using pdflatex and specifying dvipdfm which is wrong, but it isn't clear whether you intended to use pdflatex and not specify dvipdfm, or whether you intended to use latex+dvipdfm and not pdflatex

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. I intend to get PDF file at the output. The thing is, same files are working on my PC but not only my laptop where i installed a fresh windows last week.